# Overriding default parameter names in ExtJS 4 Store

Tags: json, extjs4, cross-domain, jsonp

I'm trying to override the default parameter name for limitParam in proxy for the Store. I want to make a JSONP call to http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=kathmandu&rpp=2 but instead of setting rpp directly I want to map it to limitParam and set it's value. But it's not setting through limitParam. The reason I'm doing is the parameter keys store sends (sort, dir, etc) do not match the parameters on the server side (which I've no control over). Thanks in advance.

```
    Ext.require('Ext.grid.View');
    Ext.require('Ext.util.Point');

    Ext.application({
    name: 'HelloExt',
    launch: function() {
    /*Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                title: 'Hello Ext',
                html : 'Hello! Welcome to Ext JS.'

            }
        ]
    });*/
    console.log('ok1');


    Ext.define('Video', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['from_user', 'from_user_id']
    });

    var myStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Video',
        storeId : 'restfulStore',
        proxy: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            url : 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=kathmandu',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                //root: 'data.items'
                root: 'results'
            },
            limitParam: 'rpp',
            pageParam: 'page'
        },
        listeners: {
            load: function(store, records) {
                Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
                    console.log(rec.get('from_user'));
                });
            }
        },
        sorters: [{
            property: 'from_user',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }, {
            property: 'from_user_id',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],
        //autoLoad: true,
        remoteSort: true
    });

    var p = myStore2.getProxy();
    p.limitParam = 2;



    myStore2.load();
    console.log('loads anyway??? loaded the store ...');


    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Restful Grid',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('restfulStore'),
        columns: [
            {header: "From User", width: 200, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'from_user'},
            {header: "From User ID", width: 200, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'from_user_id'}
        ],
        height: 400,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });



    console.log('store loaded!!');
}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proxy configuration is fine for what you want to do. The problem is in the way you load the store. You should not change `limitParam` which is really the config option for the **name of the param**. To affect the number of results, use the [`limit`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load) option of the load method, that you can also configure in the store with the `pageSize` option.

So, remove this:

```
var p = myStore2.getProxy();
p.limitParam = 2;
```

And instead, use the `limit` option when loading the store:

```
myStore2.load({
    limit: 2
});
```

Alternatively, you can set this in the store config with the `pageSize` option:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    // ...
    pageSize: 2
    ,autoLoad: true
});
```

You can mix both by setting a default with `pageSize`, and changing it at loading time with `limit`.

As a side note, the tweeter API doesn't seem to support sorting, so your `sorters` configuration won't have any effect on the returned results. You should switch `remoteSort` to `false` to have the returned results sorted on the client side according to your configuration.